# sed: How can I make this bash command work/work better?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

My objective is to simply to change a function call from one to another, anywhere the first one is found, recursively.  In this case, `mysql_error(` to `mysql_error_to_log(`.

In the past, I have successfully used the following grep & sed statement:

```
grep -rl connection1\.php ./ | xargs sed -i
    's/connection1\.php/account_db_user\.connection\.php/'
```

So this time I tried something similar (just a different character, `(`, being escaped):

```
grep -rl mysql_error\( ./ | xargs sed -i 's/mysql_error\(/mysql_error_to_log\(/'
```

but I receive this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 37: Unmatched ( or \(
```

It seems to be telling me that my attempts to escape `(` aren't correct.   I searched for an explanation for that sed issue on google, but didn't find anything really clear.  So what's wrong with that command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to escape `(` or `)` in quoted strings on the shell, whether those strings are quoted with single `'()'` or double `"()"` quotes.

The only reason the `\(` in the argument to grep works is because that string is not quoted.

Remember that it is the shell which deals with the quotes (and with the `\(` of the unquoted strings), not the programs the shell actually calls (grep and xarg, in your case).

So sed actually sees `\(` (not just `(`), and that has a special meaning in its regular expressions.

My general advice would be to always quote strings on the shell whenever there might be a "funny" character in them, and thus avoid escaping characters from the shell altogether.

As to the "old" example with the escaped dot `\.` - this appears to work, but one time you are escaping the dot from the shell (which would not be necessary but results in just a verbatim dot `.`), and the other time you escape the dot in a regular expression, where an unescaped dot has a special meaning, thus requiring the escaping to mean a verbatim dot.

Comment: Don't get why the ( isn't a meta-character in need of escaping in order to show as a normal character in regex.  Thought that escaping was for showing normal characters, but it certainly does the job.

Comment: There are regexps and regexps. Some regexp definitions have `(` as meta character and `\(` as a literal parenthesis, some have it the other way round. sed regexp uses `(` for literal paren and `\(` for the metacharacter. perl regexp does it vice versa.

Comment: Well that's annoying, but good to know, I'll have to keep an eye out for that issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try it without any escapes at all (that works for me).